# Какой сервер посоветуйте поставить для изучения Linux?

Tags: centos, freebsd

Хочу поставить сервер себе на старый ноутбук,но теряюсь что ставить,CentOS или FreeBSD. У кого поддержка в плане пакетов лучше? или всё равно и лучше компилить каждый пакет самостоятельно?(в первых планах поставить php 5.5.3 и apache 2.4.6)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: в стабильных дистрах php5.5 и apache2.4 нет ещё, можно  debian  sid поставить (если на поиграться)    $ apt-cache policy php5 apache2    php5:      Установлен: 5.4.4-14      Кандидат:   5.5.3+dfsg-1    apache2:      Установлен: 2.4.6-2      Кандидат:   2.4.6-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. centos6
2. freebsd не линукс

остальное не важно.

Comment: но freebsd относится к семействам UNIX

Comment: ну при таком расладе можно поставить и solaris ))

Comment: можно,но он не свободнораспространяемый и вряд ли влезет на мой старенький ноут))

Comment: наврал.свободнораспространяемая....облачная...хмм...она думаю тяжела будет

Comment: solaris -> opensolaris -> openindiana = все одно по сути и никаких облаков

Comment: Напомню, что правильное название "линукса" GNU/Linux. Где GNU - это рекурсивный акроним от GNU’s Not UNIX — «GNU не UNIX».[Ссыль][1]  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU

Answer (score 1):

Для изучения ставь Ubuntu. Все есть, инфы море.

И не гонись за сервером. Все пакеты есть (или можно доставить) в любой конфигурации.

Ставь с Иксами (для изучения проще будет).

Comment: с убунтой знаком,в этой среде сам собирал php и apache.Хотелось бы именно изучить серверную ОС и желательно без иксов

Comment: т.к. планирую подключаться к ней через ssh удалённо,т.е. будет видна лишь консоль.Как клиент хотел использовать putty

Comment: ubuntu как бы не совсем линукс)) ну т.е. типа как бы это сказать линукс для домашних домохозяек :)

Comment: почему? чем он не линукс?отключаешь все графические финтифлюшки и он становится полноценным линуксом с наилучшей поддержкой. Тот же debian

Comment: любой линукс-десктоп превращается за пару минут в линукс-сервер. На счет изучения, согласен с коллегами относительно ubuntu. На предприятии полноценно используется 4 сервера на этой системе уже 3 года, порой админы адреса забывают от частоты входа...

Comment: в виде серверов юзал CentOS, RFRemix и Debian  Больше понравились красношапочные... но это уже мое личное...

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu-server - великолепный дистрибутив, море инфы, стабилен!